# COMException due to WebPart Connection while trying to Filter provider list web part

Tags: web-part, filter, connection

In SharePoint 2010 I see the following symptoms:

We have three lists, looking up to one another in a chain.

Sample:

- **Vendors** [30] as root;
- **Projects** [100], Looking up to Vendor;
- **Deliverables** [500], Looking up to Project.

We use standard list web parts with no SPD or other customization.

We need to be able to filter the Projects by a value in the root lookup field (vendor) and then use the filtered projects to provide filter values to the web part that represents the entities lowest in the hierarchy, such as Deliverable.

Update: *The Vendor field is pulled from Projects as an additional dependent lookup, so initially it is named something like "Project: Vendor"*

The filtering works normally on a page with just the two Projects and Deliverables web parts, until we add the web part connection, at which point we cannot filter Projects by Vendor due to an error stemming from a COMException:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: One or more field types
>   are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete
>   these fields.

Has anyone solved this kind of issues before? Someone must have.

Comment: I had to resort to a workaround, still looking for opinions

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have seen this error before. It was a naming convention issue on one of the look-up fields, I would delete the field(s) in question and remake them in Designer. (No spaces or special characters in the field names)

Comment: The actual field was created as a secondary lookup, so there was a colon and a space. However, in the URL the new dispay name is used that has no spaces: idVendor